# Read data of txt file from a folder and fill textbox using javascript with using a browse button

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner of `javascript`. I want to read data from a `.txt` file that I saved in a folder and then fill textbox with this data. I don't want to use a browse button to open the file. 

Somebody can help me please ..

Comment: So you mean the path of the file should be hardcoded?? and may i know what have you tried so far

Comment: As you are new,, You should read "how to ask" and always try to explain as more as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function,its basically an [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) request to your file.

```
 function getTextFromFile(fileName,callBack)
    {
        var file = new XMLHttpRequest();
        file.open("GET", fileName, false);
        file.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            if(file.readyState === 4)
            {
                if(file.status === 200 || file.status == 0)
                {
                    var text = file.responseText;
                    callBack(text);
                }
            }
        }
        file.send(null);
    }
```

Call function like this:

```
 getTextFromFile("example.txt",function(text){

  document.getElementById("textboxid").value = text;

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use a browse button to open the file.

You **must** have either

- A browse button, or
- Drag-and-drop

E.g., the user **must** do something to explicitly give you the file to read. You cannot automatically read a file from the user's computer without a user action giving you access to the file, for perhaps obvious reasons.

Once you've done the browse button or drag-and-drop, you can use the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to read the file and fill in the textbox: [live copy](http://jsbin.com/suzagodaco)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show File Data</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type='file' id='fileinput'>
<textarea id="the-textarea"></textarea>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    var input = document.getElementById("fileinput");
    input.addEventListener("change", loadFile, false);

    function loadFile() {
        var file, fr;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        if (!input.files) {
            alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        } else if (!input.files[0]) {
            alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        } else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = receivedText;
            fr.readAsText(file);
        }

        function receivedText() {
            document.getElementById("the-textarea").value = fr.result;
        }
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it possible with XMLHttpRequest

```
function readFile(file)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", file, false);
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(req.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(req.status === 200 || req.status == 0)
            {
                var resp = req.responseText;
                alert(resp);
            }
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```

call your function from your js,Here As an argument pass the filepath for your local file.Assuming you want to hard code the filepath.

```
readFile(file:///C:Users/Test/Desktop/Sample.txt)
```

Comment: Why downvote..What's Wrong with this solution.Can you please notify..

Comment: Thanx. But this is not working.
Actually JavaScript does not allow to access local directory without a trip of server. So, either the file must save in the same folder where your HTML files are or use browse button.
I use Ajax and to get data of .txt file in textbox .